# SEO friendly url explanation?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've did some research in how to rewrite my url with htaccess for an SEO friendly url, but I have a questions:

When i rewrite from index.php?news=1 to /news/1 would my `$_GET['news']` still work? I can't seem to find an explanation on that. I want to be sure before I'll start implementing it into my website.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what your rewrite rules are. If you want help in writing right rewrite rules to achieve this let us know.

Comment: Can we see your rewrite rule? ...and are you sure that you are rewriting index.php?news=1 to /news/1 and not /news/1 to index.php?news=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work as expected.

Specifically, `mod_rewrite`'s behavior with regards to existing query strings can be surprising. As an example, let's take the following rule, which converts the URL you supplied:

```
 index.php?news=1 to /news/1
```

page name will be accessible through `$_GET['news']`.

Comment: How? One cannot simply replace this with that.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyYoghurt +1 for you

Comment: It's a valiant edit, but all you've really done is restate that it will work.  Why does `?news=1` mapped to `/news/1` still work with `$_GET['news']`?

Comment: When the client requests http://example.com/news, the server uses the rewrite rule to serve them http://example.com/index.php?p=news instead.@CrazyYoghurt

Answer (score 0):

> When i rewrite from index.php?news=1 to /news/1 would my $_GET['news'] still work?

*Yes*. `$_GET['news']` is set because you have hardcoded `news=1` into the rewritten query string.

If you have additional query parameters, *it depends*. If you've used the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (query string append) flag then *yes*, otherwise `$_GET['param']` would not be set in the URL:

```
/news/1?param=2
```